# Pairing long strings by assigning id to materialized view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to replace large strings (a couple hundred characters) with ids to create a simple materialized view pairing sequences without needing to keep the original string. I've created a subquery in PostgreSQL with an output similar to the example below (with abbreviated strings for simplicity):

```
 feat_uniquename | segment1 | segment2 | segment3 
-----------------+---------------------+----------
 SEQ000001.1     | GATA...  | TTTA...  | CTTT...
-----------------+---------------------+----------
 SEQ000001.2     | GATT...  | TTTC...  | CTTT...  
-----------------+---------------------+----------
 SEQ000001.3     | GATG...  | TTTC...  | CTTT...  
-----------------+---------------------+----------
 SEQ000001.4     | GATC...  | TTTA...  | CTTT...
```

I'm trying to condense this to look like the following:

```
 feat_uniquename | segment1 | segment2 | segment3 
-----------------+---------------------+----------
 SEQ000001.1     | 1        | 1        | 1
-----------------+---------------------+----------
 SEQ000001.2     | 2        | 2        | 1  
-----------------+---------------------+----------
 SEQ000001.3     | 3        | 2        | 1  
-----------------+---------------------+----------
 SEQ000001.4     | 4        | 1        | 1
```

Leaving long strings in the materialized view would be memory inefficient and likely slow row association, but I'm at a loss for how to proceed using just SQL. Without using an iterative process (is that even possible in SQL?), it doesn't seem possible to link the values. As a last resort, I could condense the strings using Python dictionaries, write to a delimited text file, and parse to create the materialized view.

Comment: I vote for leaving the sequences as they currently are.  After all, it represents your actual data.  There are all sorts of pitfalls with trying to map them to numerical sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have three columns of data like this, you could create a lookup table by mapping each unique value to an arbitrary index, and then join your table on each lookup and select the index column. For example,

```
WITH lookup1 AS (SELECT DISTINCT
    segment1,
    row_number() over(partition by segment1) as index1
)

SELECT
    feat_uniquename,
    index1
FROM
    original_table t1
INNER JOIN
    lookup1 t2
ON t1.segment1 = t2.segment1
```

Comment: Good idea, but what happens when a new codon gets added to the data set?  Or if one codon should be removed from the data set?

Comment: I'll give this a try. I plan to recreate the materialized view whenever the dataset changes. Thanks!

Comment: Update: row partitioning was close to what I wanted, but I ended up using row count instead.